# Powershell Active Directory DisplayName

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a powershell script that builds active directory users based on CSV file. It has the attributes defined like this:

```
    -GivenName $_.FirstName `
    -Surname $_.LastName `
    -SamAccountName $_.UserName `
```

I want to add the DisplayName attribute to combine $*.FirstName and $*.LastName with a space in the between. I tried:

```
    -DisplayName $_.FirstName + " " + $_.LastName  `
```

But the above doesn't work, it gives an error.

Can anyone kindly suggest how I can define the DisplayName attribute with the firstname and lastname from the CSV data?

Thanks

Comment: Wrap it in parenthesis.   ... and BTW: You should not use backticks. That's really the baddest style you can use ever in Powershell.

Comment: for a safer - and easier to read - way to build the parameters & values for your cmdlets, please read `Get-Help about_Splatting`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When [PowerShell looks at](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing) arguments passed to a command, each individual token is interpreted as a separate input argument.

Wrap the string concatenation in a sub-expression (`$()`) to pass it as a single string:

```
Set-ADUser ... -DisplayName $($_.FirstName + " " + $_.LastName)
```

or use an expandable string:

```
Set-ADUser ... -DisplayName "$($_.FirstName) $($_.LastName)"
```

---

As [Lee_Dailey notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60714158/powershell-active-directory-displayname/60714187#comment107420601_60714158), you might want to use a technique called ["splatting"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) to organize your parameter arguments instead of splitting them over multiple lines:

```
Import-Csv users.csv |ForEach-Object {
    $parameterArgs = @{
        Name = $_.Name
        SamAccountName = $_.UserName
        GivenName = $_.FirstName
        Surname = $_.LastName
        DisplayName = $_.FirstName,$_.LastName -join ' '
    }

    # pass our parameter arguments by "@splatting"
    New-ADUser @parameterArgs
}
```